# Почему при наследование родительского класса в pycharm не видны методы и переменные?

Tags: python, pycharm

У меня есть два класса Vectorizer и VectorizerString. Первый класс является родительским, но почему то при обращение к методам и переменным родительского класса из дочернего pycharm выдает ошибку *Cannot find declaration to go to*. С чем это может быть связано?

При этом при запуске программы все работает нормально, но при написании кода это затрудняет работу.

```
class Vectorizer():

def __init__(self):
    self.df = None
    self.scale_koef = None
    self.dict_one_hot_encoding = {}
    self.dict_bag_of_words = {}
    self.number_input_parameters = None


class VectorizerString(Vectorizer):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def input_data(self):
    input_data = {}
    for i in self.dict_one_hot_encoding.keys():
        print(i)
```

Comment: Вы про переход "control+click"? Да вроде с этим примером все в порядке

Comment: оступы так и задуманы?

Comment: @vitidev да про это

Comment: @Сергей Шашко какие отступы? Один отступ между каждой функцией в классе
классы в разных файлах